# Assembly in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio, it doesn't recognise "byte ptr" in asm. Does anyone know what I should use instead? I use visual studio because I just wanted to do a little asm next to a c++ code to speed things up a little. So could anyone also check the code, because I'm not sure about the return (this is just a test). And does this work for in also for uint?

```
__declspec(naked) void bewerken(int letter)
{
    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, 1      // ruimte maken voor 1 variabele van 1 byte
        mov byte ptr [eax], [ebp+8]
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* bYte;
    int letter;
    printf_s("Voer een letter in:\n");
    letter = getchar();

    if (letter < 128)
    {
        __asm 
        {
            push letter
            call bewerken
            add esp, 4
            mov byte ptr bYte, eax
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("Te hoog.\n");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

note: "BYTE PTR" doesn't compile either

Comment: If you're using MSVC inline assembly for a performance boost, you're gonna need to use larger blocks than that. MSVC assembly is known to have a lot of startup and ending overhead due the fact that all operands must be pass in via memory.

Comment: Try `mov al, byte ptr [esp + 8]` you might want to do `xor eax, eax` first depending on how you use eax though. edit: Also I don't think there should be much overhead here due to the naked function, I've used them quite a bit and have never seen the overhead Mysticial is talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no valid addressing mode `mov whatever [eax], [ebp+8]`

One can `mov al, [ebp+8]` or `mov ax,[ebp+8]` and `mov eax,[ebp+8]` and also `mov rax,[ebp+0x132220]`, but also one can move an immediate to an address with immediate offset. That would be the only case, where explicit width attribute is needed: `mov byte ptr 0x01,[ebp+8]` at least that's the way it worked in the era of debug.exe...

In every other case the width of the operation should be clear.